# disable kendo ui controls in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I am using kendo ui controls for the first time in mvc.

1> @Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model => model.field).Name("txtFirstName")

how do I reset the value to empty string and disable a kendo textboxfor using jquery?

for some controls I am able to do something like this, but for the kendo.Textbodfor() I donot know what to pass in the .data()

```
var txtLastName= $("#LastName").data("kendoAutoComplete");

txtLastName.value("");

txtLastName.enable(false);
```

2> this partial view only renders a textbox - how to reset the value to an empty string and disable the textbox rendered by the partial view

```
<li>@Html.Partial("~/Views/xyz/_AutoComplete.cshtml")</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor` the generated output doesn't generate a Kendo widget it is simply an `input` element.

You just need to use some jQuery or Javascript to do what you want.

```
$('#txtFirstName').removeAttr("value")
$('#txtFirstName').prop("disabled", "disabled")
```